# Why is this foreign key constraint incorrectly formed?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

How I arrived at this question is a spaghetti of error messages in itself.

First, it was error message `1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`.

...from trying to insert data with an absolutely valid foreign key.

Now I've re-created the tables in order to duplicate the problem and found a new error, which brings me closer to the root cause.

```
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `covers` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entities` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 100001
PARTITION BY KEY() PARTITIONS 10 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `covers` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  ,
  CONSTRAINT `covers-id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `entities` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

Its a new database designed in Workbench.  The Forward Engineer script created the tables without error, but it seems there is a problem with them.

Adding the output from `show engine innodb status`

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2016-06-21 17:42:46 7f7ffa000700 Error in foreign key constraint of table `baka`.`IF`:
Create  table `baka`.`IF` with foreign key constraint failed. Referenced table `baka`.`entities` not found in the data dictionary near '
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `entities` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB'.
```

Comment: You can run `show engine innodb status` and find the exact details somewhere in the output (look for "last foreign key error" or something similar). Whatever, I believe that partitions and foreign keys don't necessarily work well together.

Comment: Have you checked the collation of both tables? They both need to be of the same collation.

Comment: ALso you could try setting the autoincrement flag

Comment: On Fiddle it failed due to the `PARTITION BY`

Comment: Logically, I understand that a partitioned table can't have foreign keys or other indexes in itself and still be efficient. But does this suggest that other tables can't key with the partitioned table either?  Because that was unexpected if true.

Comment: @dnoeth I understand that partitioned tables are internally named different than normal tables. Thanks for confirming the partition failure.  The solution seems to be in avoiding foreign key constraints entirely, and I'm fine with that.  Maybe you or someone could write an answer.

Comment: You cannot use foreign keys and partitioning together. Neither the referenced nor the table that gets the foreign key can be partitioned. You can and should however use indexes, they are still a lot more efficient than not having one (it's just that mysql has to look into more index-structures then).

Comment: `covers-id` failed . Dash is an operator, DO NOT USE IT FOR NAMING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partitioned table can't be referenced by other table's foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem.
The source of mine was that the tables didn't have the same engine. So my solution was to put the same engine for both tables.

Comment: This was a lifesaver :) Thank you.

Comment: You saved a lot of hours for me mate. Thank You. :)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. The error was that the dump file i was restoring from had the tables in the wrong order. So by manually creating the tables referenced to first solved the problem.